# Selenium WebDriver - Use an integer variable as value for an input field?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I declared an integer. And I have an input field. And I want to use whatever I have stored in the integer as value for that input field. Is it possible?

Here is the code, with the ideal ending:

```
int avPartQty = Integer.parseInt(avPartQty_substring);
actions.searchResultsVa_SelectAvailPartQty(driver).sendKeys(+avPartQty); //wish it was that easy, lol.
```

This is my text box:

```
<input name="txtQty" value="1" maxlength="5" id="txtQty" class="textboxnumeric" onkeypress="return ValidateForDecimal(this, event);" style="color:Black;width:25px;" type="text">
```

Comment: Why not use `.sendKeys(avPartQty_substring)`?

Comment: Will converting the int to string help or you want to send that as int?

Comment: you can simply pass sendKeys(String.valueOf(avPartQty));.

Comment: Read the question carefully. My problem is not how to convert int to strings. I needed the WebDriver method on how to use an int as input for a field, which someone already put below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below code for this,

int avPartQty = Integer.parseInt(avPartQty_substring);
actions.searchResultsVa_SelectAvailPartQty(driver).sendKeys(avPartQty+"");